# Installing Ffmpeg for Windows Server 2012

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-server-2012

I want to convert a number of `.wmv` files to `.mp3` format in a batch, so I need `ffmpeg` for that but I can't install `ffmpeg` on Windows Server 2012. I have done all the steps described on this link http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows but it's not working. What to do now?

Comment: Please tell us exactly how it is "not working".

Comment: @slhck Well i installed it according to the same steps but when i use the command line, it says that ffmpeg is not recognized as any internal or external command, i think there is an issue with environmental variables because there was no path by default and i created the first one.

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg is a command line utility that can be from any folder where it is located. You do not need to install it to run it. If you want to run it:

1. Go to the folder where it is located
2. Right click inside the folder while holding down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and click on the `Open command window here` option
3. Run the program with whatever option you needs `>ffmpeg -arguments`

However if you want to be able to access it from any folder without it being locally present, you need to add its location to the `PATH` environment variable  ([for more details see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)), as described in the wikihow article.

If this is just a one time use, I would recommend simply copying it and running it from where ever necessary. If you want to add it to the path, the steps outlined in the wikihow article or the linked question should help you complete this task.

You can also set the path permanently using the `setx` command (from the command line)

```
setx PATH C:\folder\with\ffmpeg\
```